# Getting Extra escape character while loading the data from Onprem to Redshift DB using Informatica Cloud

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, iics

We're migrating the Datastage workflow (having source as Oracle) to Informatica cloud (using Redshift as out target db).

One of the table column is having escape character in the data.
Source - RON\
TGT - RON\\

The expectation is to load only one escape character which is coming from the source through Informatica cloud.
Thanks in advance.

I tried everything like asking the newly introduced AI's , regex,replace char in sql and expression through Informatica cloud, however unable to succeed. Please help if we need to change anything at secure agent level or something which this issue can be fixed as soon as possible.